# wordpress css background image parameter

Tags: css, wordpress

i was studying on wordpress administration theme.

i notice somethig i've never seen before:

```
.meta-box-sortables .postbox:hover .handlediv{background:transparent url(../images/menu-bits.gif?ver=20100610) no-repeat scroll left -111px;}
```

what does '?ver=20100610' mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a .gif image, most likely nothing. It's probably there for no reason other than as a quick-and-dirty means of bypassing caching when the developer/designer update the theme to a new version (presumably the value of 'ver' would change to the new release date, forcing browsers and proxies to retrieve the potentially-changed image file anew from the server instead of using their cached version).

Comment: mh, it could be the answer ;) another question on the fly: i noticed that the gif contains 3 images inside. how can i select one image instead of others?

Comment: Without seeing the exact image, I can't say for certain, but it's most likely a typical "sprite sheet". In CSS, you specify "no-repeat" for the background (as I now see in the snippet above), and then specify the appropriate offset (again, as I see above) to show only the part you want. Here's one article explaining them: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ Google "CSS sprites" for lots more information than you could ever need!

Comment: Just one more thing to toss in: The article I linked to (which I hadn't read closely prior to posting) calls the entire "master" image (the one that combines multiple smaller images) the "sprite", when in fact the smaller ones are the "sprites" and the big image is the "sprite sheet". Just a minor nitpick, really, but if you're going to get into this technique it will help to have the same vocabulary as everyone else!